# Concatenate multiple rows into one line and group by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with my code: I want to concatenate multiple rows into one string or text and then order by date

```
select distinct 
    no_rm,
    riwayat_penyakit,
    berat_badan,
    keluhan,
    stuff((select distinct ',' + diagnosa
           from tb_rekam_medis
           where no_rm = 'RM001' 
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as diagnosa,
    stuff((select distinct ',' + tindakan
           from tb_rekam_medis
           where no_rm = 'RM001' 
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as tindakan,
    id_dokter,
    poli,
    tgl_pemeriksaan
from
    tb_rekam_medis
where 
    no_rm = 'RM001'
```

[image: here is the schema of my table]

[image: here the sample data I have]

I want that data to be:

```
"B37.9, B37.3" for date 2019-07-16 and
"B37.9" for date 2019-07-09
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Images are not a good way to share data. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also, the screenshots don't look like sql server.

Comment: Hi.  Is this SQL Server and if so, what version? The way to make this happen has changed with more recent versions of SQL Server.

Comment: *I have a problem with my code* ... and what is the problem?

Comment: i using sQL server 2014, this image i capture when me not using ssms

Comment: iwant to group every data using date but it's not work

Comment: the data shown is just dummy data

Answer (score 0):

i was found the answer

```
select distinct a.no_rm,
            a.riwayat_penyakit,
            a.berat_badan,
            a.keluhan,
            STUFF((select distinct ',' + diagnosa
                   from tb_rekam_medis
                   where no_rm = 'RM001'
                     and tgl_pemeriksaan = a.tgl_pemeriksaan FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') as diagnosa,
            stuff((select distinct ',' + tindakan
                   from tb_rekam_medis
                   where no_rm = 'RM001'
                     and tgl_pemeriksaan = a.tgl_pemeriksaan FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') as tindakan,
            a.id_dokter,
            a.poli,
            a.tgl_pemeriksaan
```

from tb_rekam_medis a
where no_rm = 'RM001'